# Can a linear system be chaotic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, chaos-theory, linear-systems

A chaotic system is a system in which infinitesimal perturbations of a parameter can result in large changes in the behavior of the system.  I *thought* it is not possible for a linear system to exhibit chaotic behavior, but some recent papers (e.g., [this paper](https://www.hindawi.com/journals/complexity/2017/6020213/)) indicate that infinite-dimensional linear systems can be chaotic.  It seems that *any* system that includes unbound particles would be infinite dimensional, in that wavefunctions of those particles would belong to an infinite-dimensional Hilbert space.  So is it actually possible for a linear QM system to be chaotic?

Comment: Frankly, you're playing mix-and-match with definitions of chaos - to the detriment of your question. If you just take the definition of chaos used in the paper you linked and blindly apply it to QM then there's a high chance that you will get "chaos" - but not in any sense that can be meaningfully connected to the existing notions, to the underlying classical system, and indeed to any physical observable at all. So: define 'chaos', and define 'linear system'.

Comment: This would not be the first time I've made the mistake of mixing definitions ("metric" vs "metric", for example).  I'll pose a separate question that might help.

Comment: As a sidenote: That paper seems to be a strange choice of a starting point for chaos in infinite-dimensional linear systems. If you look into its citations, you will find many papers on this going back to the early nineties (which the paper you cite still considers “recent” for some reason – many of these papers are older now than the term *chaos* was when they were published).

Comment: It seems most papers rely heavily on the DeVaney definition of chaos and the key components of this definition is topology transitivity and density of periodic points.  Hypercyclicity is key to establishing the transitivity requirement for linear functions. I have found at least one paper that says there are cases where subgroups using finite terms can show hypercyclicity. I think your question is interesting because “chaos” is not appearing to be well defined in math. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.4390.pdf

Comment: I wrote up the trivial answer for basic definitions of "_chaos_" and "_linear_".  That said, under these basic definitions, this seems pretty straight-forward, so dunno if there's some special restriction that might add complexity to the situation?

Answer (score 3):

***tl;dr*–**  Yes, any function, including chaotic functions, can be decomposed into an infinite linear system, therefore infinite linear systems can be chaotic.

---

A trivial example would be
$$
f\left(x\right)
~=~
\sum_{\forall i}{
a_i \, \delta\left(x-p_i\right)
}
\,,$$
where $\delta\left(x\right)$ is the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) and there's one amplitude/position tuple, $\left<a_i,\,p_i\right> ,$ for each discriminable $x ,$ $x_i .$  In other words, just think of an [infinite-resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dense_set) [piece-wise function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise).

Then $f\left(x\right)$ is non-chaotic in the special case that $\require{cancel} \left| a_i - a_{i-1} \right| ~\cancel{\!\! \gg \!\!}~ \left| p_i - p_{i-1} \right| ~~ \forall i \,,$ though $f\left(x\right)$ is [almost certainly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_surely) chaotic.  In other words, an infinite-resolution piecewise function is non-chaotic if we select the values for each point to differ by not much more than the distance between the points, but since this is an extremely contrived special case, almost all infinite-resolution piece-wise functions are chaotic.

Since this is a linear combination of trivial atoms (I selected the Dirac delta since it's pretty easy to reproduce in most numeric systems, to help keep this explanation more general), yup, linear systems of infinitely many components can be chaotic.

Notes:

1. Any function $f\left(x\right)$ can be [decomposed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_decomposition) into such an infinite-resolution piece-wise function.
2. Chaotic behavior is observer-subjective.  This appears in the above where we define chaotic-quality as being a function of $\require{cancel} \cancel{\!\! \gg \!\!} ,$ which is a fuzzy qualifier.

Comment: Or even a single linear function, but applied with infinitely many steps. 3N+1, Wolfram's Rule 90.

Comment: I think this answer is incorrect. The chaos from an infinite linear system approximation comes from the linear system approximation itself, not from a failure to compute the linear system. Then it's not chaos in a linear system, it's chaos in the modeling system (one meta level).

Comment: @NicSzerman: I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  The answer above was meant to point out a simple answer based on grade-school-level math; issues such as computability aren't generally of concern in such a trivial context.

Comment: @NicSzerman: I am curious about why you used the term **"_failure to compute_"** -- what sort of failure might you imagine?

Answer (score 1):

There is certainly a definition issue if one accepts that “linear” equations describe systems that do not interact and “nonlinear” equations describe ones that do.  Under this definition “chaos” can only arise in interacting systems described by “nonlinear” equations.

However, “linear” equations can be solved by matrix methods, and assuming the problem can be represented with a square matrix, the system will have a characteristic polynomial associated with the matrix.  Finding the roots of the polynomial is how one would solve the system of equations.  Characteristic polynomials can be difficult to solve for roots especially in high degree systems but can be solved using iterative methods such as Newtonian methods.  It is in solving for the roots of a polynomial that fractal/chaotic behavior can be observed, and quite beautifully at that (see link below).

So chaos can exist in linear systems just not necessarily in a direct way.

https://pi.math.cornell.edu/~hubbard/NewtonInventiones.pdf

Update:  There are some good introductory papers on infinite dimension linear systems and chaos. One which deals with this topic for biological models is available here http://www.scielo.org.za/pdf/sajs/v104n5-6/a0610406.pdf

Comment: Chaotic behavior in a solving method is, of course very different from chaotic behavior in the equations being solved.  I think a general definition of a linear system would be that given  initial conditions I1(t=0) that produce a behavior O1(t), and I2((t=0) that produce behavior O2(t), then the system will produce behavior aO1(t)+bO2(t) with initial conditions aI1(t=0) +bI2(t=0).  It's not obvious to me that this precludes the possibility that, for example, O1(t=0) is chaotic.  Maybe it should be obvious--

Comment: @EmilioPisanty, In [https://www.osti.gov/servlets/purl/6502672-EwROhd/], it is conjectured that chaos is always due to the impossibility of handling infinities with finite systems, and asserted that "even the most deterministic system will behave stochastically due to unavoidable and unknown truncations of information".  That is, *computing* the behavior of a linear system can lead to nonlinear (chaotic) behavior.  Given that all measurements depend on finite systems, this seems to imply that it is not possible to determine by measurement that a system is absolutely linear.  True?