# Can an affine first-order polynomial system be chaotic?

Tags: terminology, conventions, definition, chaos-theory, linear-systems

While studying chaos theory, one of the basic principles presented to me was that chaos only occurs in deterministic nonlinear systems. This pointed me to learn more about the differences between linear and nonlinear systems. At first, I had to have a clear definition of linearity and what defies a linear or nonlinear system. I have encountered multiple definitions of linearity or nonlinearity, which seemed to cause confusion around the clear definition of linear systems. To be exact, I'm interested in solving this confusion around affine functions, and linear polynomials in particular.

In order to present the exact problem, I have to show you my conflicting definitions of linearity.

> I've encountered a lot of definitions of
> nonlinearity similar to the one in the book Chaos Theory Tamed by Garnett P. Williams:
>
> > **Nonlinear** means that output isn't directly proportional to input, or that a change in one variable doesn't produce a proportional change or reaction in the related variable(s)
> >
> > A **nonlinear equation** is an equation involving two variables, say $x$ and $y$, and two coefficients, say $b$ and $c$, in some form that doesn't plot as a straight line on ordinary graph paper.
>
> This can be easily negated to produce a definition of linearity.
>
> On the other hand, more formal mathematical sources, define linearity in strict linear algebra form, such as this explicit one from [Linearity - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearity#In_mathematics):
>
> > In mathematics, a linear map or linear function $f(x)$ is a function that satisfies the following two properties:
> >
> > - Additivity: $f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)$.
> > - Homogeneity of degree 1: $f(\alpha x) = \alpha f(x)$ for all $\alpha$.

The problem arises when talking about linear polynomials. The first definition implies that all linear polynomials (polynomials of degree 1) are linear, even if they do not satisfy both of the properties of the second definition. In fact, linear polynomials in the form
$y=mx+n$
satisfy both if and only if $n=0$ and are otherwise defined as *affine functions*, and do not fall under the more specific definition of *linear*.

Thus, if we strongly define a linear system as a finite set of linear equations that must satisfy the property of superposition—which in itself is defined by Homogeneity and Additivity, we imply that affine linear polynomials do not count as linear, and so a system of affine function, even though they are linear polynomials, is not considered a linear system.

This is where my question arises - since logically, and from what I have already learned of chaos theory, it doesn't seem as if affine linear polynomials should be considered nonlinear in a chaos standpoint of view since I simply cannot see how chaos can erupt in such equations. I would be glad to receive some clarification on this, and perhaps some other point of view that I have not yet considered.

**Edit:** From more research and looking at other related questions I've concluded that an affine system is nonlinear from a definitive point of view, even if the system consists of affine linear polynomials. Thus, I'm interested in understanding whether an affine system, as opposed to a strictly linear system, can be chaotic?—again, even if constructed from affine first-order polynomials.

Comment: I guess both, although I am more interested in classifying an affine system of linear polynomials as a linear or nonlinear system. If I am shown how such a system can be chaotic than it implies that such a system is nonlinear, so that also provides an answer.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/437073/2451

Comment: I think that first definition may just be written in a weird way.  I mean, yeah, the first clause says that a function is linear only if it's of the form $y=mx ,$ **_but_** the second clause specifies that functions where $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=m$ also qualify, allowing $y=mx+b .$  Since the second clause of the definition is a strict generalization of the first, the first clause would seem unnecessary; I'd speculate that they included it anyway, as to present the simpler concept $\left(y=mx\right)$ before generalizing it $\left(\text{to}~y=mx+b\right) .$

Comment: I agree, and this is where I'm confused - since the first definition classifies $y=mx+b$ to be linear (which is implied from the second clause), but the second one classifies it as affine - thus nonlinear since $y=mx+b$ where $b\neq0$ does not meet the properties of superposition. So I'm confused whether a system of affine equations (of the form $y=mx+b$) is considered a linear system or not, as both definitions contradict each other on that.